# statusCode 401 errorUnauthorized при обратном геокодировании

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode

Беру пример из песочницы по ссылке наверху, вставляю свой ключ отсюда

https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/services/3/

И ничего, получаю ошибку 401. Что я делаю не так?

upd:

Последовал совету YaCor' и написал в поддержку. Выяснилось, что не так я делал следующее:
Я указал привязку по ip адресам для локального хоста. Этого не нужно было делать) Без привязки всё работает. Надеюсь, это когда-нибудь кому-нибудь поможет

Comment: Это вопрос не для SO. Проверить ключ может только поддержка API Яндекс Карт - maps-api@support.yandex.ru

Comment: Если ключ правильный и рабочий, проверьте, что удалили угловые скобки из кода при вставке ключа -  <ваш API-ключ>.

Comment: Я пробовал и с угловыми скобками и без, пробовал с - и без них. Мб попробовать другой ключ?

Comment: Если ключ получен для верного сервиса и не заблокирован, а код оставлен исходный, ошибок быть не должно. Рекомендую всё же обратиться в поддержку Яндекса с деталями - пример кода на https://jsbin.com/ и полученным ключом. А может какие блокировки стоят на ваш домен или IP - это тоже только поддержка скажет.